# How to select a option from the list which is displayed inside 'input' tag instead of 'Select' tag through Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

Using Selenium Webdriver and Java, I want to select a option from the list which is displayed inside 'input' tag instead of 'Select' tag.

Please find below details-

The GUI is as following-
[Please find the GUI image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5hLK.png)

```
<td nowrap="" valign="middle" colspan="3" rowspan="1">
<div class="mceGridField siebui-value mceField">
<input type="text" name="s_6_2_158_0" value="" aria-labelledby="BGC_Type_Label" aria-label="Type" style="height: 24px; width:80px;" class="siebui-ctrl-select siebui-input-popup siebui-align-left siebui-input-align-left ui-autocomplete-input" aria-describedby=" s_6_2_158_0_icon" maxlength="30" tabindex="0" role="combobox" autocomplete="off" data-seq="0" aria-readonly="false">
<span class="siebui-icon-dropdown applet-form-combo applet-list-combo" id="s_6_2_158_0_icon" data-allowdblclick="true"></span></div>
</td>
```

The GUI List of options are as following-
[Please find the GUI image of option list after clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7VpY.png)

I am using below code to select one of the option from the  list-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='s_6_2_158_0_icon']")).click();
```

But still I am not able to select any option.
Can you please help ?

Comment: Share some code.  And there is an ID so why not find by id instead of xpath.

Comment: are you getting an exception when clicking on it with xpath? My guess is you have to treat is as a dropdown, click/type in 'Type' then wait for 'Fix' to become visible before clicking it

Comment: The shared html is for only input tag , can you share html with some options which are available in JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `sendKeys` method btw-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='s_6_2_158_0_icon']")).sendKeys("Fix");
```

And it's better to use the id -

```
driver.findElement(By.name("s_6_2_158_0_icon")).sendKeys("Fix");
```

Comment: It's never recommended to use these kind of ID's.

Answer (score 0):

To invoke `click()` on the desired option from the list you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[name^='s_'][aria-labelledby='BGC_Type_Label'][aria-label='Type']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@name,'s_')][@aria-labelledby='BGC_Type_Label' and @aria-label='Type']"))).click();
  ```